# Mirroring a haar cascade in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a haar cascade for an open hand, which detects right hands easily, but doesn't always work on left hands. Is there a way to mirror the cascade in OpenCV? This way I could detect both hands more robustly (I guess).

I don't like mirroring the image, since I would have to do it very often.

Comment: your guess is wrong. do flip the images instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it is possible, but why don't you mirror the image instead of the classifier (i.e. [`cv::flip()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#flip))?

Comment: I see, but how often should you perform mirroring? Mirroring is a relative inexpensive operation it should has effect onto the real-time processing. The best you can do is to train another classifier to the mirrored training database.